# What does GlobalAveragePooling1D do in keras?

Tags: keras, nlp, embedding

In the embedding example here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings

```
result = embedding_layer(tf.constant([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]))
result.shape
TensorShape([2, 3, 5])
```

Then it explains:

```
When given a batch of sequences as input, an embedding layer returns a 3D floating point tensor, of shape (samples, sequence_length, embedding_dimensionality). To convert from this sequence of variable length to a fixed representation there are a variety of standard approaches. You could use an RNN, Attention, or pooling layer before passing it to a Dense layer. This tutorial uses pooling because it's the simplest. 

The GlobalAveragePooling1D layer returns a fixed-length output vector for each example by averaging over the sequence dimension. This allows the model to handle input of variable length, in the simplest way possible.
```

Then the code:

```
embedding_dim=16

model = Sequential([
  vectorize_layer,
  Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, name="embedding"),
  GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  Dense(1)
])
```

The GlobalAveragePooling1D should calculate a single integer for each word's embedding of dimension = n. I don't understand this part:

```
This allows the model to handle input of variable length, in the simplest way possible.
```

Similarly:

```
To convert from this sequence of variable length to a fixed representation there are a variety of standard approaches.
```

In each embedding layer, input length is already fixed by the parameter 'input_length'. Truncation and padding are used to ensure the fixed length of the input. So what does it mean by saying GlobalAveragePooling1D is used to convert from this sequence of variable length to a fixed representation? What does the 'variable length' mean here?

Answer (score 3):

I'm studying ML myself, so it's just my take on understanding GlobalAveragePooling1D.

The key to understanding this example is the quote slightly above the passage you were quoting:

> It can embed sequences of variable lengths. You could feed into the embedding layer above batches with shapes (32, 10) (batch of 32 sequences of length 10) or (64, 15) (batch of 64 sequences of length 15).

So within a single fit all sequences will have the same length. But then you can take the same model and fit it on other sequence lengths. Thanks to GlobalAveragePooling1 the lengths of the vectors that get to the Dense layer will be the same (in fact they will be equal to the embedding dimension).

This is how I understand the flow:

[image: word preprocessing flow]

Answer (score 0):

The tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D layer's input is in the example a tensor of batch x sequence x embedding_size.

It returns a matrix of batch x embedding_size, by averaging over the sequence dimension. The average is only over one dimension therefore the 1D.

The averaging can handle handle different sequence sizes. For example sentences of any length.

Answer (score 0):

Once the vectorize_text is passed to the embedding layer, it returns a matrix where no of rows represent words and no of columns represent embeddings for which u chose 16, so there be 16 columns. As mentioned in the answer of
**Roman**
, GAP calculates average along columns of embedding matrix which yields as many values as there are no of columns. For 16 columns, GAP return 16 values; each is the mean to the corresponding column.
Each sentence is a vector of words, each word in embedding output is a vector of floating points, by mentioning variable lengths it means that you can have different no of words in input, but GAP would always yield a fixed-length representation, 16 in this case.
Hope it helps :)